# Playframework forms

Tags: java, playframework-2.3, ebean

I'm creating a form to allow users to edit my objects, but it seems that only the object fields that are editable in the form are available within my controller once the form is submitted. My example is a user object that I present in a form to allow the user to edit the name field, when they submit the form my controller needs to determine if this is a new user or an exiting user. To determine this I check the ID field, but since the ID field is not editable on the form it is null, when I check it in the controller.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: private static final Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class);

Comment: private static final Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class);
public static Result details(Long id) {
    final User user = User.findById(id);
    ...
    Form<User> filledForm = userForm.fill(user);
    return ok(edit.render(filledForm));
}

public static Result save(){
    Form<User> boundForm = userForm.bindFromRequest();
    User user = boundForm.get();
}

Only the class fields that are editable in form are returned by boundForm.get().  If I use a <hidden> field as suggest by Sivakumar I can use boundForm.data().get("..") to retrieve the hidden field data but that's ugly and insecure

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, keep your id has hidden input in template. So that it will be available for you in controller after user hitting form's submit button.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value='@userForm.field("id").value' >
```

Comment: Thanks Sivakumar, I knew I can do that but I wonder why there is no better method than having to include every field in the form that I need access to in the controller.

Comment: Actually if I hide the field it is not returned in the data submitted. I need to make it editable which of course is not what I want.

Comment: @CrispyOz Can you post your hidden input element placed in your view and make sure your input `name` attribute, should exactly matches your property name.

Comment: Sivakumar I can use boundForm.data().get("id") to retrieve the hidden field data but hidden fields are  insecure.

Comment: @CrispyOz Without proper validation in server side, even visible fields are insecure. You need to validate the incoming request, whether it is from authenticated person, if it is then process rest like edit/delete otherwise return an error message.